# Scan OTG mount point in android

Tags: java, android, usb-otg

I need to access a pen drive connected via OTG to android device.
With expolorer I can find the mount point in /storage/usbdisk.
But, how can I find the mount moint dynamicallu via code?

Thank you!
Roberto

Comment: Is it in getExternalFilesDirs() ?

Comment: @robyg I am trying to access other device in my android phone through otg. If you have solution can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid the only way to access OTG on a wide range of devices is by querying all these directories:

```
/storage/UsbDriveA     (all Samsung devices)
/storage/USBstorage1   (LG G4, V10, G3, G2, other LG devices)
/storage/usbdisk       (Moto Maxx, Turbo 2, Moto X Pure, other Motorola devices)
/storage/usbotg        (Sony Xperia devices, Lenovo Tabs)
/storage/UDiskA        (Oppo devices)
/storage/usb-storage   (Acer Iconia Tabs)
/storage/usbcard       (Dell Venue -- Vanilla Android 4.3 tablet)
/storage/usb           (HTC One M7, and some Vanilla Android devices)
```

Tested on my collection of devices and the devices of 3 other people, and a quick trip to Bestbuy for testing the latest flagships. The only popular devices I know I'm missing are Hawuei/Xioami devices based in China, which are becoming popular in English countries.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Aaron, after many search I think that your is the only way :-)

Comment: @Aaron I am trying to access other device in my android phone through otg. If you have solution can you help me?